# NPAPI plug-in not loading in Safari

Tags: safari, npapi, browser-plugin

everyone, I made a NPAPI plugin, it works fine in firefox, but in Safari, it tells me can not find plug-ins.This is my registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MozillaPlugins\@llf.com\WebGame

Descripton: REG_SZ "MP"

Path: REG_SZ "D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\plugins\npFireFoxGame.dll"

ProductName: REG_SZ "npFireFoxGame"

Vendor: REG_SZ "llf"

Version: REG_SZ "1.0"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@llf.com/WebGame\MimeTypes\application/webgame
```

my HTML file:

```
<embed width=1024 height=768 type="application/webgame">
```

Please help me.

Comment: And you're showing the code for Mozilla plugins, but how about Safari?

Comment: My operating system is windows 7

Comment: I use the SDK, the xulrunner-13.0.1.en-US.win32.sdk

Comment: this is my def file:
 NP_GetEntryPoints   @1
 NP_Initialize       @2
 NP_Shutdown         @3
 NP_GetMIMEDescription @4

Comment: @lc.: Plugin registration for all browsers except IE is the same and it just carries Mozilla names for historic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

`@llf.com\WebGame` should be `@llf.com/WebGame`. Also, `MimeTypes` entries usually contain the values `Description` and `Suffixes` (both `REG_SZ`).

Otherwise:

- Does it still work in Firefox when your DLL is located somewhere other than FFs plugin folder (you shouldn't use that one)?
- Does it behave differently when you use `object` instead of `embed`?
- Does your DLL get loaded at all (use depends.exe or the like)?
- Have you tried running Safari in depends.exes tracemode to see how far it gets and what fails?

Comment: Thank you, I used your method is still not solve the problem, I want to use FireBreath without direct use npapi

Comment: @llfllf: Ok, if you want to continue without FireBreath at some point post some results for the above steps.